# Web view with pull to refresh

Tags: android-webview

I am beginner with Android development.

I have used https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh library for 'Pull to Refersh' feature.

I have configured web view for this feature and it's working fine.

The issue is when we pull to refresh, the web view gets stuck and i can not scroll the existing page.

Please help to resolve this issue or suggest alternate library for this feature.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a webpage with scrolling functionality. In every scroll down and up data is loaded on web view pages. In my code we uses a number with next and previous button. All of web pages are store on web server. If we press next than data is show on web pages.